# Does Outlook OST File auto-resize

Tags: microsoft-outlook, pst, size

Good morning,

I want to confirm something about OST files.

I have noted that the OST file size just keep increasing and does not decrease.
Even if I select the time bar of the inbox to be lets say 1 yr, I feel anything that Outlook had for the previous years, it just hides it versus clean/delete those emails from the OST file to keep the size down.

Now, I have to recreate the OST by lowering the time bar to 3 months or less. which redownloads all emails again to create a fresh OST of lower size.

This is causing issues with our 128GB HD laptops.

Can anyone confirm this behaviour or have a solution to this?
I know we can use the OWA to access the shared mailbox, but that depends on Internet connection and has it own challenge for some users.

Hopefully my question is clear enough. Thanks.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/reduce-the-size-of-your-mailbox-and-outlook-data-files-pst-and-ost-e4c6a4f1-d39c-47dc-a4fa-abe96dc8c7ef

Answer (score 0):

What is the size of OST file now?
You could refer to this article to reduce:
https://www.nucleustechnologies.com/blog/solve-oversized-ost-file-issues-in-outlook-using-manual-tricks/